# Как получить пользователей онлайн?

Tags: php

Сейчас я делаю так: при каждой загрузке страницы, я обновляю в кеше ключ "`{$user->id}.online`" на 5 мин. Если ключа нет — пользователь не в сети.

Этот способ хорош, когда надо проверить конкретного пользователя зная его `id`.
Но как получить всех пользователей онлайн? Приходится загружать всех юзеров (благо их пока мало) и у каждого проверять "`{$user->id}.online`". Это ужасно. Есть ли способ лучше?

Comment: Если использовать Memcached, то можно получить список ключей. http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.getallkeys.php

Comment: По-твоему, это норм?

Comment: а зачем отдельный ключ в кэш кидать, а не массив ID хранить?

Comment: @teran каким образом проверять онлайн тогда? Из этого массива id сами будут удаляться?

Comment: @GroZa по поводу удаления надо думать. я делал счетчик на .net с использованием `SignalR`, посмотрите в сторону [аналогичных решений для php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473356/is-there-any-javascript-tcp-soket-library-for-php-like-signalr-with-net). там асинхронные запросы на сервер шлются от клиента при коннекте/дисконнекте. В результате можно было получать когда пришел новый человек, либо клиент перешел на другую страницу, либо он завершил сеанс. Данные при этом ходили в обе стороны. То есть при изменении количества человек, все клиента получали уведомление.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с записью, которая содержит список предполагаемых онлайн юзеров:

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$now = time();
$life = 5 * 60;
$m->set("{$user->id}.online", true, $life);

if (($online_users = $m->get('online_users')) === false) {
    $online_users = array($user->id => $now);
    // нужно ли записывать время в значение элемента под вопросом
    // возможно хватит true или 1   
} else {
    $online_users[$user->id] = $now;
    foreach ($online_users as $id => $time) {
        // ключи {$id}.online остаются для проверки
        if (false === $m->get("{$id}.online")) {
            unset($online_users[$id]);
        } else {
            // тут что-то делаем с юзером, который онлайн
            // $id содержит его номер
            // $time содержит время последней отметки оналайн
        }
    }
}

$m->set('online_users', $online_users, $life);
// в переменной $online_users массив id (номера в ключах массива) юзеров онлайн
```

P.S. Тестирование не проводилось. Выгоды/проигрыши не вычислялись.

Comment: Я думал над этим вариантом. А вот если одновременно на сайт зайдет 100 человек, по получается надо 100 раз записать в online_users массив — обратиться по одному и тому же ключу, то произойдет некая блокировка на запись в Memcached/Redis? Не знаю, норм это или нет. Но вариант хороший)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вычислить с помощью сессий.

Для сессий по умолчанию определено файловое хранение, где каждый сеанс индивидуально хранится на диске. Это означает, что для того чтобы выяснить сколько пользователей `online` (я предполагаю, "online = набор существующих сессий `$_SESSION['$nickname']`), вам нужно будет открыть все файлы сессий, сохраненные на диске, и проверить, сколько уникальных `nicknam'ов` существуют внутри сессий.

Стоит учитывать что:

- Сессии не разрушаются сразу при закрытии браузера. Это означает, что сервер должен придумать какой-то алгоритм на основе времени, чтобы решить, кто в сети, а кто нет.
- Сеансы изолированы друг от друга так что `$_SESSION["test1"]` не может совместно использоваться несколькими другими сессиями.

Comment: Думаю, этот вариант хуже, чем у меня сейчас.

Comment: А еще может быть такое, что файлы сессий вообще не удаляются :) И пока сервер не начнет выдавать ошибку о нехватке места на диске об этом ни кто не знает.

Answer (score -1):

Табличка в БД с двумя полями

```
CREATE TABLE users{
    user_id INT,
    last_login TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
}
```

При входе пользователя

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, last_login) values ($id, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_login=NOW();
```

Соответственно, количество "активных"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE NOW() - last_login<$desired_timeout
```

Comment: Это медленно на каждую загрузку страницы добавлять запись в БД.

Comment: @GroZa Что бы подобное утверждать, необходимо как минимум сначала проверить. Какие у вас ожидаются нагрузки? Если речь идет о   порядках 10 человек в секунду, то о задержке на общение с БД имеет смысл смотреть, если меньше (а судя по таймауту в 5 минут это так), то я вас умоляю.

Comment: Мне не надо пробовать чтобы понимать, что использование кеша в памяти куда быстрее, чем делать SQL запросы. Хочется сделать решение универсальное, а не "до 10 человек в секунду юзай БД, а вот после 50 надо будет все переделывать"

Comment: @GroZa взаимоисключающие параграфы вижу я. Если вам нужно универсальное решение, то это как раз БД, а не костыли с кешем, который имеет тенденцию очищаться например. Если вам хочется прям космических скоростей, то смотрите на решения in-memory database. Весь хайлоад как-то живет с базами и не жалуется, а вам пуговицы не того цвета.

Comment: "Весь хайлоад как-то живет с базами и не жалуется" — пруф на "INSERT INTO users..." при каждом запросе в хайлоад проекте будет?

Comment: Инфа об онлайне не является важной и, поэтому, очищение кеша не будет являться проблемой. Для того он и кеш. Все равно через минуту всё вернется.

Comment: @GroZa включив элементарную логику можно догадаться, что в любом проекте использующем авторизацию/историю входов пользователей как минимум на этапе авторизации используются БД и, при открытом соединении, производство одного апдейта дает настолько мизерный оверхед, что кеширование того же самого в локальный кеш может получиться даже затратнее.

Comment: " настолько мизерный оверхед, что кеширование того же самого в локальный кеш может получиться даже затратнее." - спасибо, можете не продолжать.

Comment: @GroZa Мир полон удивительных вещей и самое безблагодатное, что можно сделать это зарыть голову в песок и твердить "этого не может быть", впрочем воля ваша